# Comparing PHP current time to a mysql datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, compare

I have searched and all questions are related to the comparison being in the query.
I'm building an e-commerce website and I have a feature that allows the customer to return products 7 days upon date of purchase.

So I have, a column in mysql that tells when they bought. And I have to compare the current time (Philippines) to the mysql column, so the system can tell if they will have the option allowed.

The logic I'm thinking of but can't find the right syntax:

```
(inside the while loop that fetches columns as arrays, my variable is $info)
$php_current_datetime = date_now_in_php_format;
$purchase_datetime = $info['purchase_date'];
$expire_date = $info['purchase_date'] + 168 hours;
```

Then compare it

```
if($php_current_datetime < $expire_date){
echo "show the option";
}
else{
echo "already expired";
 }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: can be done in pure sql `purchase_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY > NOW()` ...

Comment: then how do I use if 'show option' or 'already expired' if I query it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making all the values timestamps and calculate the difference between them in seconds.

```
$secDifference = 60*60*168;

$dtObject= new DateTime($mysqlDatetime);
if ($dtObject->getTimestamp() > time()-$secDifference) {
    //show the option
}
```

Comment: not every "7 days" is 168 hours of 60 minutes with 60 seconds